# How to restrict page access in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

so I have this NodeJS Express application where I have a CRUD system, so I want to restrict the Create Update And Delete pages for admins (or people I choose) only, but I don't want to have a login system, how is that possible? If not, what other options than a login system do we have to do this?
Thanks...

Comment: From your statement, I am assuming you don't have much security concerns. One solution I would implement: For each admin, generate a random string(let's call it password) and store it on server-side. When admins make call to server, ask them to provide their 'password' with each request. (or just store it in cookie after the first successful request). You have a partially 'secure' CURD system.

Comment: @Abdus How would the server know that the admin is the one who made call to the server? because i don't want "provide the password"  to be visible to everyone who enters the website..

Comment: then restrict access to protected resources using IP address.